# Determine RCP application is newly installed or cached

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, java-web-start, jnlp

Is there any way to check my RCP application is first time installed (via Webstart) or is run from cached (for example. desktop shortcut) during runtime.
What I have in mind is implement DownloadServiceListener and check if one of the static resource is downloaded (if yes - new, if no - cached).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `installer-desc` element of the JNLP to invoke some code that writes an attribute in the `PesistenceService`. See more information on the [JNLP API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/jnlpAPI.html).

Comment: thanks. its fine for my question but i realize that actually its not what I wanted to ask, sorry. I would like to know when the Webstart is run from shortcut or from a new JNLP. When i click new JNLP file, it might not be necessary install again since its cached.